# Can't delete/disassociate an InfoPath form from a form library

Tags: infopath, custom-form, form, form-library

I have a form library, when I go to library settings>form setting>I see "Internet Explorer is required to use this feature."

I am already using internet explorer. but, still I am getting that error.

How can I delete the form?

[image]

Comment: try to add  your site URL to compatibility view list in tools menu of IE  , also at local intranet sites

Comment: It's restricted because of company policy may be because I checked and everything is greyed for compatibility view settings.

Comment: @JoeCutler which version of IE you are using?

Comment: IE 11
Version:  11.0.9600.18376CO